# Can you give a general expression for the rate of rising water poured in an object?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric, finite-element-method

Given an 3-d object defined by a set of parametric equations (x, y, z), can you write a formula expressing the rate that a liquid rises as it's poured into this object at a constant flow rate?

Assume the object is an enclosed solid of revolution with a hole at the top.

(I have seen multiple questions like this asked before but they are not nearly as general as this one.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint?**
You can find a unique path/parameterization for a any curve that would yield constant speed with respect to the re-parameterization (using arc length as one example).
Let the volume occupied by the liquid be your curve, with the original parameter, and differentiate $z$ with respect to the arc-length (times your flow rate).

Alternatively a general expression would be the reciprocal of the $z$ derivative of the volume (times your constant).

Comment: Probably better ways to explain the above, and better ways to do it, proper. :) Let me know if this helps, if you want. If it doesn't I'll make it more explicit, tomorrow..